# What's the point of Content-Script-Type and Content-Style-Type

Tags: html, stylesheet, specifications, w3c, script-tag

Consider these two lines:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
```

From the W3's documentation on [Scripting](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html), in the section [The default scripting language](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.1):

> Authors should specify the default scripting language for all scripts in a document by including the following META declaration in the HEAD

Yet it continues in [Local declaration of a scripting language](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.2) to say:

> The type attribute must be specified for each SCRIPT element instance in a document. The value of the type attribute for a SCRIPT element overrides the default scripting language for that element.

Seems to me like there's an over-specification here.  Why are *both* the `meta` and per-`script` type declarations required?  What's the point of a mandatory default if we 'must' declare each tag individually anyway?

Either let the default **be** the default, or just state that each tag needs it's own type - or is the wording here just getting me tripped up?  The same language is used with reference to [style sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html) as well.

Comment: Just to clarify specific of W3C's way of doing technical documentation.
According to this http://www.w3.org/2001/06/manual/#RFC they have specific meaning for key words to Indicate Requirement (e.g., "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED") [[KEYWORDS RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)].

**SHOULD**  This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item...
**MUST**  This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the definition is an absolute requirement of the specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<script>` and `<style>` elements are only one way of adding scripting and styling to HTML.

For scripting, we have event handler attributes, for styling HTML 4.01 defines the `<link>` element, the `Link:` HTTP header and the "style" attribute. In each of these cases, specifying the language is not mandated, so the fall-back would be the value of Content-Script-Type and Content-Style-Type.

For example: the scripting section says:

> Documents that do not specify default
>   scripting language information and
>   that contain elements that specify an
>   intrinsic event script are incorrect.
>   User agents may still attempt to
>   interpret incorrectly specified
>   scripts but are not required to.
>   Authoring tools should generate
>   default scripting language information
>   to help authors avoid creating
>   incorrect documents.

and the styling section has an equivalent statement:

> Documents that include elements that
>   set the style attribute but which
>   don't define a default style sheet
>   language are incorrect. Authoring
>   tools should generate default style
>   sheet language information (typically
>   a META declaration) so that user
>   agents do not have to rely on a
>   default of "text/css".

Note that these requirements are not DTD expressable, so validators that rely on a DTD won't flag violations as errors.

Whether any browser actually pays any attention to the settings, I've no idea.

Comment: So the case you're making is that the Content-X-Type declarations are only meant for cases where type='Y' isn't available? That currently only applies to the `style` attribute (as the HTTP Link header (to my knowledge) is not even yet an RFC).  I still don't see why type='Y' is necessary when you've defined a Content-X-Type default.

Comment: To answer your second point first, I guess it's an additional stronger restriction for `<style>` and `<script>`. The `type` attribute **must** be specified, the default-x-tyoe **should** be specified. It may have had a lot to do with backward compatibility and stating what the HTML 4 authors *ought* to be the case, and what they believed worked in browsers at the time the spec was written.

Comment: @Chris - It's not just the "style" attribute. "onload", "onclick" etc can't have scripting language defined by any other means. `<link>` (definitely) and `Link:` (probably) can name a style language to use, but there is no **must** or **should** level requirement for their use.

Comment: @Chris - The most recent RFC for the HTTP Link header appears to be [RFC 5988](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988). It's at PROPOSED STANDARD state.

Comment: I over-read the spec - good call, the `Content-X-Type` declaration is a "should" and not a "must" meant to handle as you say `onclick`s, etc.  I guess it still seems pointless that I "must" specify the `type` when I "choose" to supply the `Content-X-Type` but now I understand much more clearly the meaning, purposes, and differences of the two specs.  Thanks!