# Bad values in meta tags

Tags: html, meta-tags

I've got a problem when I pass the html5 validator to my site from w3c validator. The errors are next:

```
Bad value Content-Script-Type for attribute http-equiv on element meta
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" >

Bad value expires for attribute http-equiv on element meta
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 26 Feb 1997 08:21:57 GMT" >

Bad value pragma for attribute http-equiv on element meta
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" >

Bad value Cache-Control for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" >
```

What are the correct values to meta tags to pass html5 validator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 meta Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655526/html5-meta-validation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For HTML5 you use a cache manifest file in the header.
This is an example of how to use:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#manifests

Also, you force no cache with this:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

This is a good tutorial on how to use the cache manifest file:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-manifest-file-creating

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I still having the same problem with the next meta tag:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" >` with the message error: **Bad value Content-Script-Type for attribute http-equiv on element meta**

Do you know any solutiont? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JoséCarlos - For javascript in the header, you can just use `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`. For additional information, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320084/why-is-meta-http-equiv-content-script-type-mostly-unused

Comment: where exactly is the HTML 5 example? Your link doesn't take me to anything specific.

Comment: @StealthRabbi - It looks like they updated the page, I have edited the link in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is wrong! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657962/352260) is a good answer.

To quote Alohci:

> Putting caching instructions into meta tags is not a good idea, because although browsers may read them, proxies won't. For that reason, they are invalid and you should send caching instructions as real HTTP headers.

Addendum:
For Apache and .htaccess you could use

```
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault value      or
ExpiresByType text/css  "access plus 1 month"
...
</IfModule>
```

PHP have headers_sent() and header() function for that.

```
function header_no_cache () {
    \header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
    \header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
    \header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
}
```

Point is that caching instructions should be in header. Not in html file.

Comment: OK, and how do you send them as real HTTP headers?

Comment: Except this doesn't work for static HTML5 only websites that uses an external unconfigurable web server from a host provider.