# No caching in HTML5

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache, cache-manifest

In HTML4 we used stuff like

```
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" />
```

to get the browser to not cache the pages.

What should I use in HTML5 to get the browser not to cache my pages. **I don't want any pages at all cached**.

I've seen something about

```
    <html manifest="example.appcache">
      ...
    </html>
```

but it seems like a lot of work to specify all the pages in the whole web application just to get the browser not to cache anything.

Is there a simpler way?

If I omitt the manifest part from the html tag, will that make the browser not cache anything? I.e.

```
    <html>
      ...
    </html>
```

Or will it take that as an ok to cache everything?

Comment: The manifest specifies settings for the application cache - a very cool new feature of HTML5 but it has nothing to do with what you are attempting. I'd stay away from using it for now. My own experience has shown it to be not quite ready for prime time.

Answer (score 4):

[Answer#12693786](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693786) might be helpful.

Here is an example of `your-manifest-file` to force updates to all resources.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
```

and append `manifest` attribute to `<html>` element.

```
<html manifest="your-manifest-file">
```

Required for all HTML files you want to disable cache.
Can not be avoided because it is specification of HTML5.

Comment: Beware, this Cache Manifest feature has been removed from the Web standards.

Answer (score 2):

Cache settings are optimally handled by the response headers from the web server. I would research changing those settings. Including a header like:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,post-check=0,pre-check=0
```

will stop all chaching in my experience. I have never had consistent desired behavior setting cache behavior using meta tags in any version of HTML.

Comment: in php `header("Cache-Control: max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,post-check=0,pre-check=0");` on top of your script

Answer (score 0):

I think if you leave out the manifest attribute, it defaults to no cache. I know that on firefox, you can use add-on tools like Firebug or HttpFox to check if the page is cached. 
Not sure about other browsers, but most likely it's under "Network" tab of developer tools.