# HTML5 vs XHTML Strict 1.0 (Metatags)

Tags: html, xhtml, meta-tags, xhtml-1.0-strict

I got a question regarding validating the HTML code of my webpage. I have a XHTML 1.0 Strict webpage and I am  trying to convert it to a HTML5 page. When I changed the doctype to the HTML5 format and run it against the the [w3cvalidator](https://validator.w3.org) and the [validator.nu](https://html5.validator.nu) websites I got the following results:

```
Bad value Pragma for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element meta.
Bad value Expires for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element meta
Bad value CACHE-CONTROL for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element meta.
```

My HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

I know that (after reading several topics on StackOverflow, like: [Bad Values in Metatag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693630/bad-values-in-meta-tags), caching in HTML5 is different. But I still wonder why does those metatags works just fine within XHTML and not in HTML5? I do not quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't "work" in XHTML, clients still ignore them. The XHTML DTD just doesn't forbid them because it is only as specific as "This attribute should have *some text* in it".

HTML 5 attempts to restrict meta data to stuff that actually does something useful.