# Validating XHTML code with validator.nu web service

Tags: xhtml, w3c-validation

I am using the API validator.nu:

https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service:-Input:-POST-body

I want to force validation according to strict or transitional XHTML doctype :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

In the documentation, they are asking to send the request header:
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

I think that XHTML is a an XML-like code ?!

After sending the content which contains non-valid markup like <br> (no closing "/"), the web service doesn't return any errors. I think that is hanlding code as HTML5.

How to validate XHTML document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your question:

> I want to force validation according to strict or transitional XHTML doctype

You can't. Validator.nu [does not support DTD based validation](https://about.validator.nu/#no-dtd). It is an (X)HTML 5 validator, not a DTD based validator. The obsolete [W3C validator provides an API](https://validator.w3.org/docs/obsolete-api.html) that does support DTD checking, and other XML validators based on DTDs are available.

You should probably move to (X)HTML 5 though. It better reflects what browsers actually support than XHTML 1.0 does.

> In the documentation, they are asking to send the request header:
>   Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> I think that XHTML is a an XML-like code ?!

The documentation does say that that is only an *example*. The Content-Type for an XHTML document (including an XHTML 5 document) is `application/xhtml+xml`.

That should trigger XML parsing, so `<br>` should trigger an error. It will still be checking against the HTML 5 specification though, not the XHTML DTDs.

Comment: It worked, but I also got an unexpected error "Bad value “Content-Type” for attribute “http-equiv” on XHTML element “meta” for <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: @Simohammedhttc — Why is it unexpected? You've made two claims about what the content-type of the document is and they don't match.

Comment: I have to change the value of http-equiv, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320084/why-is-meta-http-equiv-content-script-type-mostly-unused

Comment: Note that moving to XHTML5 will entail changing lots of things to make it work, e.g. named entity references into numerical character references.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this :

1. Goto : [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/)
2. Choose validate by ***URI*** or **File Upload** or **Direct input**.
3. Then in **More Options** choose **UTF-8** for character encoding and
   **XHTML Strict** for Document Type.
4. Then click on **Check**.

You will get the XHTML Strict output.

Comment: I am querying the vadilator programmatically.